# php : how to extract datas from an array_merge

Tags: php, array-merge

after an array_merge on 2 sql queries i got an array like this :

```html
array:4 [?
  0 => array:1 [?
    "mistake" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [?
    "mistake" => "5"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [?
    "mistake" => "1"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [?
    "mistake" => "11"
  ]
]
```

the idea now is to get the number of "mistake" single values.. in this case for example i should have an input of "3", because i have 3 kinds of "mistake" here.

Thank you

Comment: You need output as *3*

Answer (score 1):

```
echo count(
    array_unique(
        array_column($yourArray, 'mistake')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `array_unique` and `array_column` if you need output as **3**

```
<?php
$array_merge = [
    [ "mistake" => "1"],
    [ "mistake" => "5"],
    [ "mistake" => "1"],
    [ "mistake" => "11"],
];
$temp = array_unique(array_column($array_merge, 'mistake'));
echo count($temp);
?>
```

**Working Demo:** https://3v4l.org/MYUB1